# Conditionally return data

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return, conditional-statements, return-value

I have this function:

```
 getFace(/* string */ face_name, /* int */ w, /* int */ h, /* int */ z) {
    const am = this.props.assetsManager;
    return {
      backgroundSize: 'contain',
      position: 'absolute',
      width: `${w}px`,
      height: `${h}px`,
      zIndex: z
  };
```

If `face_name` is `face2` I need to return an additional style i.e. `backroundColor: red`

How do I add a condition to the return statement?

Comment: Try incorporating `...backroundColor: (condition) ? 'red' : ''` to your return statement (under zIndex).

Comment: @MoA how can i use multiple if else statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an object and add to it according to a condition like this:

```
getFace( /* string */ face_name, /* int */ w, /* int */ h, /* int */ z) {
  const am = this.props.assetsManager;
  let returnObj = {
    backgroundSize: 'contain',
    position: 'absolute',
    width: `${w}px`,
    height: `${h}px`,
    zIndex: z
  };

  if (face_name == 'face2')
    returnObj.backgroundColor = 'red';

  return returnObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use function to add conditional class

```
class BookmarkArticle extends React.Component {
  getClassName(){
     let classname="";
     if (condition){
       return classname
     }else{
       return classname
     }
  }
  render(){
     return(
         <div className={this.getClassName}></div>
)}
}
```